# SIGXCPU raised by setrlimit RLIMIT_CPU later than expected in a virtual machine

Tags: c++11, linux-kernel, signals, virtualbox, setrlimit

[EDIT: added MCVE in the text, clarifications]

I have the following program that sets `RLIMIT_CPU` to 2 seconds using `setrlimit()` and catches the signal. `RLIMIT_CPU` limits CPU time. «When the process reaches the soft limit, it is sent a `SIGXCPU` signal. The default action for this signal is to terminate the process. However, the signal can be caught, and the handler can return control to the main program.» ([man](https://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit))

The following program sets `RLIMIT_CPU` and a signal handler for `SIGXCPU`, then it generates random numbers until `SIGXCPU` gets raised, the signal handler simply exits the program.

**test_signal.cpp**

```cpp
/*
 * Test program for signal handling on CMS.
 *
 * Compile with:
 *     /usr/bin/g++ [-DDEBUG] -Wall -std=c++11 -O2 -pipe -static -s \
 *                  -o test_signal test_signal.cpp
 *
 * The option -DDEBUG activates some debug logging in the helpers library. 
*/
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <csignal>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

using namespace std;

namespace helpers {
    long long start_time = -1;
    volatile sig_atomic_t timeout_flag = false;
    unsigned const timelimit = 2;   // soft limit on CPU time (in seconds)

    void setup_signal(void);
    void setup_time_limit(void);

    static void signal_handler(int signum);

    long long get_elapsed_time(void);
    bool has_reached_timeout(void);

    void setup(void);
}

namespace {
   unsigned const minrand = 5;
   unsigned const maxrand = 20;
   int const numcycles = 5000000;
};


/*
 * Very simple debugger, enabled at compile time with -DDEBUG.
 * If enabled, it prints on stderr, otherwise it does nothing (it does not
 * even evaluate the expression on its right-hand side).
 *
 * Main ideas taken from:
 *   - C++ enable/disable debug messages of std::couts on the fly
 *     (https://stackoverflow.com/q/3371540/2377454)
 *   - Standard no-op output stream
 *     (https://stackoverflow.com/a/11826787/2377454)
*/
#ifdef DEBUG
#define debug true
#else
#define debug false
#endif


#define debug_logger if (!debug) \
                        {} \
                     else \
                        cerr << "[DEBUG] helpers::"

// conversion factor betwen seconds and nanoseconds
#define NANOS 1000000000

// signal to handle
#define SIGNAL SIGXCPU
#define TIMELIMIT RLIMIT_CPU

/*
 * This could be a function factory where and a closure of the signal-handling
 * function so that we could explicitly pass the output ofstream and close it.
 * C++ support closures only for lambdas, alas, at the moment we also need
 * the signal-handling function to be a pointer to a function and lambaa are
 * a different object that can not be converted. See:
 *  - Passing lambda as function pointer
 *    (https://stackoverflow.com/a/28746827/2377454)
*/
void helpers::signal_handler(int signum) {
    helpers::timeout_flag = true;

    debug_logger << "signal_handler:\t" << "signal " << signum \
                 << " received" << endl;
    debug_logger << "signal_handler:\t" << "exiting after " \
                 << helpers::get_elapsed_time() << " microseconds" << endl;

    exit(0);
}


/*
 * Set function signal_handler() as handler for SIGXCPU using sigaction. See
 *   - https://stackoverflow.com/q/4863420/2377454
 *   - https://stackoverflow.com/a/17572787/2377454
*/
void helpers::setup_signal() {
    debug_logger << "set_signal:\t" << "set_signal() called" << endl;

    struct sigaction new_action;

    //Set the handler in the new_action struct
    new_action.sa_handler = signal_handler;

    // Set to empty the sa_mask. It means that no signal is blocked
    // while the handler run.
    sigemptyset(&new_action.sa_mask);

    // Block the SIGXCPU signal, while the handler run, SIGXCPU is ignored.
    sigaddset(&new_action.sa_mask, SIGNAL);

    // Remove any flag from sa_flag
    new_action.sa_flags = 0;

    // Set new action
    sigaction(SIGNAL,&new_action,NULL);

    if(debug) {
        struct sigaction tmp;
        // read the old signal associated to SIGXCPU
        sigaction(SIGNAL, NULL, &tmp);
        debug_logger << "set_signal:\t" << "action.sa_handler: " \
                     << tmp.sa_handler << endl;

    }

    return;
}


/*
 * Set soft CPU time limit.
 * RLIMIT_CPU set teg CPU time limit in seconds..
 * See:
 *   - https://www.go4expert.com/articles/
 *         getrlimit-setrlimit-control-resources-t27477/
 *   - https://gist.github.com/Leporacanthicus/11086960
*/
void helpers::setup_time_limit(void) {
    debug_logger << "set_limit:\t\t" << "set_limit() called" << endl;

    struct rlimit limit;
    if(getrlimit(TIMELIMIT, &limit) != 0) {
        perror("error calling getrlimit()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    limit.rlim_cur = helpers::timelimit;

    if(setrlimit(TIMELIMIT, &limit) != 0) {
        perror("error calling setrlimit()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (debug) {
        struct rlimit tmp;
        getrlimit(TIMELIMIT, &tmp);
        debug_logger << "set_limit:\t\t" << "current limit: " << tmp.rlim_cur \
                     << " seconds" << endl;
    }

    return;
}


void helpers::setup(void) {
    struct timespec start;
    if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &start)) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    start_time = start.tv_sec*NANOS + start.tv_nsec;

    setup_signal();
    setup_time_limit();

    return;
}


long long helpers::get_elapsed_time(void) {

    struct timespec current;
    if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &current)) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    long long current_time = current.tv_sec*NANOS + current.tv_nsec;
    long long elapsed_micro = (current_time - start_time)/1000 + \
                                ((current_time - start_time) % 1000 >= 500);

    return elapsed_micro;
}


bool helpers::has_reached_timeout(void) {
    return helpers::timeout_flag;
}


int main() {
    helpers::setup();

    ifstream in("input.txt");
    in.close();

    ofstream out("output.txt");

    random_device rd;
    mt19937 eng(rd());
    uniform_int_distribution<> distr(minrand, maxrand);

    int i = 0;
    while(!helpers::has_reached_timeout()) {
        int nmsec;

        for(int n=0; n<numcycles; n++) {
            nmsec = distr(eng);
        }

        cout << "i: " << i << "\t- nmsec: " << nmsec << "\t- ";
        out << "i: " << i << "\t- nmsec: " << nmsec << "\t- ";

        cout << "program has been running for " << \
            helpers::get_elapsed_time() << " microseconds" << endl;

        out << "program has been running for " << \
            helpers::get_elapsed_time() << " microseconds" << endl;

        i++;
    }

   return 0;
}
```

I compile it as follows:

```
/usr/bin/g++ -DDEBUG -Wall -std=c++11 -O2 -pipe -static -s -o test_signal test_signal.cpp
```

On my laptop it correctly gets a `SIGXCPU` after 2 seconds, see the output:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -v  ./test_signal                                                                     
[DEBUG] helpers::set_signal:    set_signal() called
[DEBUG] helpers::set_signal:    action.sa_handler: 1
[DEBUG] helpers::set_limit:     set_limit() called
[DEBUG] helpers::set_limit:     current limit: 2 seconds
i: 0    - nmsec: 11 - program has been running for 150184 microseconds
i: 1    - nmsec: 18 - program has been running for 294497 microseconds
i: 2    - nmsec: 9  - program has been running for 422220 microseconds
i: 3    - nmsec: 5  - program has been running for 551882 microseconds
i: 4    - nmsec: 20 - program has been running for 685373 microseconds
i: 5    - nmsec: 16 - program has been running for 816642 microseconds
i: 6    - nmsec: 9  - program has been running for 951208 microseconds
i: 7    - nmsec: 20 - program has been running for 1085614 microseconds
i: 8    - nmsec: 20 - program has been running for 1217199 microseconds
i: 9    - nmsec: 12 - program has been running for 1350183 microseconds
i: 10   - nmsec: 17 - program has been running for 1486431 microseconds
i: 11   - nmsec: 13 - program has been running for 1619845 microseconds
i: 12   - nmsec: 20 - program has been running for 1758074 microseconds
i: 13   - nmsec: 11 - program has been running for 1895408 microseconds
[DEBUG] helpers::signal_handler:    signal 24 received
[DEBUG] helpers::signal_handler:    exiting after 2003326 microseconds
    Command being timed: "./test_signal"
    User time (seconds): 1.99
    System time (seconds): 0.00
    Percent of CPU this job got: 99%
    Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:02.01
    Average shared text size (kbytes): 0
    Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0
    Average stack size (kbytes): 0
    Average total size (kbytes): 0
    Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 1644
    Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
    Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 0
    Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 59
    Voluntary context switches: 1
    Involuntary context switches: 109
    Swaps: 0
    File system inputs: 0
    File system outputs: 16
    Socket messages sent: 0
    Socket messages received: 0
    Signals delivered: 0
    Page size (bytes): 4096
    Exit status: 0
```

If I compile and run in a virtual machine (VirtualBox, running Ubuntu), I get this:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -v  ./test_signal                                                                     
[DEBUG] helpers::set_signal:    set_signal() called
[DEBUG] helpers::set_signal:    action.sa_handler: 1
[DEBUG] helpers::set_limit:     set_limit() called
[DEBUG] helpers::set_limit:     current limit: 2 seconds
i: 0    - nmsec: 12 - program has been running for 148651 microseconds
i: 1    - nmsec: 13 - program has been running for 280494 microseconds
i: 2    - nmsec: 7  - program has been running for 428390 microseconds
i: 3    - nmsec: 5  - program has been running for 580805 microseconds
i: 4    - nmsec: 10 - program has been running for 714362 microseconds
i: 5    - nmsec: 19 - program has been running for 846853 microseconds
i: 6    - nmsec: 20 - program has been running for 981253 microseconds
i: 7    - nmsec: 7  - program has been running for 1114686 microseconds
i: 8    - nmsec: 7  - program has been running for 1249530 microseconds
i: 9    - nmsec: 12 - program has been running for 1392096 microseconds
i: 10   - nmsec: 20 - program has been running for 1531859 microseconds
i: 11   - nmsec: 19 - program has been running for 1667021 microseconds
i: 12   - nmsec: 13 - program has been running for 1818431 microseconds
i: 13   - nmsec: 17 - program has been running for 1973182 microseconds
i: 14   - nmsec: 7  - program has been running for 2115423 microseconds
i: 15   - nmsec: 20 - program has been running for 2255140 microseconds
i: 16   - nmsec: 13 - program has been running for 2394162 microseconds
i: 17   - nmsec: 10 - program has been running for 2528274 microseconds
i: 18   - nmsec: 15 - program has been running for 2667978 microseconds
i: 19   - nmsec: 8  - program has been running for 2803725 microseconds
i: 20   - nmsec: 9  - program has been running for 2940610 microseconds
i: 21   - nmsec: 19 - program has been running for 3075349 microseconds
i: 22   - nmsec: 14 - program has been running for 3215255 microseconds
i: 23   - nmsec: 5  - program has been running for 3356515 microseconds
i: 24   - nmsec: 5  - program has been running for 3497369 microseconds
[DEBUG] helpers::signal_handler:    signal 24 received
[DEBUG] helpers::signal_handler:    exiting after 3503271 microseconds
    Command being timed: "./test_signal"
    User time (seconds): 3.50
    System time (seconds): 0.00
    Percent of CPU this job got: 99%
    Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:03.52
    Average shared text size (kbytes): 0
    Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0
    Average stack size (kbytes): 0
    Average total size (kbytes): 0
    Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 1636
    Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
    Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 0
    Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 59
    Voluntary context switches: 0
    Involuntary context switches: 106
    Swaps: 0
    File system inputs: 0
    File system outputs: 16
    Socket messages sent: 0
    Socket messages received: 0
    Signals delivered: 0
    Page size (bytes): 4096
    Exit status: 0
```

Even running the binary compiled on my laptop, the process gets killed after around 3 seconds of elapsed user time.

Any idea of what could be causing this? For a broader context see, this thread: https://github.com/cms-dev/cms/issues/851